# Make div non-transparent to cover original div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div "whitebox" which is basically a div that should cover my original "stimuli" div. It goes smooth and appears nicely, yet it does not cover the original div but seems to be transparent so that I can still see my original div though it. But I want it to be covered completely.

Apparently 'opacity' does not fix it.

```
<div id="stimuli"> Just press B and get started... </div>

$("#whitebox").fadeIn("fast").delay(500).fadeOut("fast");
```

CSS:

```
#whitebox{
    background: #fc3a54;
    opacity: 1;
    position:absolute;
    height: 80%;
    width: 70%;     
}
```

Is there a simple trick to fix the transparency issue with my code above, or any other hints?

Comment: May be easier for us if you add a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) of the problem in question.

Comment: so are you saying that despite `opacity: 100%;` the div is still slightly transparent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using an image with #fc3a54 colour instead of using the background function, you can then use z-index to insure your whitebox is in front

Comment: One more question about this: it works fine, but any ideas how I could remove the border around this 'masking' image? I set border: none in CSS but it still has a tiny border.

Comment: There should not be a border on an image thats just colour it sounds like the boarder is part of the image, if thats not the case throw it on jsfiddle and post up the link

Answer (score 0):

Are you positive #whitebox is covering #stimuli? Also, jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut will toggle the display property so if you start with an element that has display:none and run fadeIn on it it will show it. You can use fadeToggle (https://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) as well.